how to use substrate-rpc-client query storage
I am trying to use substrate-rpc-client for querying a storage item in our chain, the documentation is very sparse on how to go about this. just says
    client.storage(StorageKey(vec![]), Some(H256::zero())).await.unwrap();

    // if all type params are not known you need to provide type params
    StateApi::<H256>::storage(&client, StorageKey(vec![]), None).await.unwrap();

suppose i want to query system.account_balances for a address what is the right way to use this module and to get that?
